# Does an RV need a mezuza?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah, vehicles-transportation

My son asked me if a mobile home needs a mezuza. I did not know if any of the following factors make a difference towards its requirement of a mezuza:

- It is mobile.
- In some circumstances, it is a recreational home only lived in when going on trips.

Do these (or any other factors) affect its requirement for having a mezuza?

Comment: If there are any scenarios, not addressed in the question that I think is a dupe, please edit those in your question, here.

Comment: @DanF That question seems to be about temporary residences. An RV is a permanent residence. I think seeing how they are different is easier than seeing how they are the same.

Comment: It's really unclear that an RV is a permanent residence. For some, it's like a car as well as a hotel room. You drive it around and you park it somewhere. The question is how long are you parking it and staying in the same place? However, there are numerous people that live almost their whole lives in their RV and stay in the same place. (Ah, the benefits of no mortgage payments!) For such people, it seems clear to me that they need a mezuzah. So, that's part of what I feel you need to specify in your question.

Comment: @DanF I'm not sure what needs to be more clear - I specified that my question is _because it is mobile_.  If my question was missing information I would add it, but negating the mistaken addition of other information is not my responsibility in posting a question. Pointing out that the mobile home is not actually a rabbit is not my responsibility.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. There's a difference between the nature of the residence and how you, personally, use it. We know that the RV is meant to be a mobile home - that's its normal use. But, if you leave it in one place for a long time, halachically, it's not exactly, "mobile". That's what I'm inquiring - how do you use it; not how it's intended to be used.

Comment: Not a dupe. This is asking based on the mobility; that asks based on the fact that he doesn’t own it.

Comment: The other one, on the other hand, does make this a dupe.

Answer (score 6):

[Rabbi Kaganoff](http://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/mezuzah/) says that the point is not that it is mobile but how it is used. That is, it appears that even if he drives around in it, if he lives in it permanently he should put up a mezuzah (though possibly without a bracha). It appears that the reason is that its purpose is to provide a dwelling. On the other hand, a car, whose purpose is transportation, does not require a mezuzah.

> What about a Mobile Home?
>
> The Minchas Yitzchak (2: 82) discusses whether someone who lives
>   permanently in a mobile home is required to put up a mezuzah,
>   concluding that he is required to do so; however the Minchas Yitzchak
>   is uncertain whether he should recite a brocha when he puts it up.

Rabbi Kaganoff mentions this concept when he discusses [whether an elevator would require a mezuzah](http://rabbikaganoff.com/does-an-elevator-require-a-mezuzah/)

> Dayan Weiss questions whether an elevator requires a mezuzah, since it
>   constantly moves and cannot be considered a residence. He compares an
>   elevator to a moving residence, regarding which we find a debate as to
>   whether it requires a mezuzah. Rav Avraham Dovid of Butchatch, usually
>   called “the Butchatcher,” rules that a moving residence requires a
>   mezuzah. According to this opinion, someone who lives in a van or
>   truck requires a mezuzah on the door, even if he constantly drives it
>   to new locations (Daas Kedoshim 286:1)!
>
> The major annotator to the Butchacher’s commentary, the Mikdash Me’at,
>   disagrees, contending that a moving residence is considered a
>   temporary dwelling and never requires a mezuzah. In a different
>   responsum, Dayan Weiss deliberates whether mobile homes require a
>   mezuzah, since people often reside in them, whereas using a bus or
>   automobile as a residence is considered temporary and does not require
>   a mezuzah (Shu’t Minchas Yitzchak 2:82; see also Chovas HaDor pg. 37).

Comment: +1 - consider reposting this over by the other question to which mine is a dupe.

Comment: @Yez I voted based on a dupe of the wrong question. But, as you can see, it really depends on how the RV is used. *Bivracha*.

Comment: The Agudah floor in NYC has a mezuzah outside the post of each elevator door / exit. I think it's on the right side when you exit the elevator going into the hallway of the office. Besides questioning if the elevator needs a mezuzah, I don't think the office needs one either. No one lives there except for some rodents.

Comment: Do the offices have a mezuzah or just the front? It may be in order to make a statement like a shul that has a mezuzah even though it is not a residence.